# Random SVG icons won't load

Tags: html, css, svg

I wanted to use icons with the ability to change their color and size on the fly with CSS. I decided to go with SVG icons, inspired by the way CSS Tricks uses SVG icons on their site.

Here is how I did it (similar to CSS Tricks):

In my footer template I added something like:

```
<footer>
    <!-- Amazing footer -->
    <!-- ... -->
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="0" height="0" display="none">
      <symbol id="icon-search" viewBox="0 0 470 470">
        <title>icon-search</title>
        <path d="M447.05,428l-109.6-109.6c29.4-33.8,47.2-77.9,47.2-126.1C384.65,86.2,298.35,0,192.35,0C86.25,0,0.05,86.3,0.05,192.3   s86.3,192.3,192.3,192.3c48.2,0,92.3-17.8,126.1-47.2L428.05,447c2.6,2.6,6.1,4,9.5,4s6.9-1.3,9.5-4   C452.25,441.8,452.25,433.2,447.05,428z M26.95,192.3c0-91.2,74.2-165.3,165.3-165.3c91.2,0,165.3,74.2,165.3,165.3   s-74.1,165.4-165.3,165.4C101.15,357.7,26.95,283.5,26.95,192.3z"></path>
      </symbol>
    </svg>
</footer>
```

And now I can use the icons anywhere I want like so:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search here...">
    <button type="submit">
        <svg class="icon-svg icon-search" width="22px" height="22px">
            <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#icon-search"></use>
        </svg>
    </button>
</form>
```

And it works... however sometimes on page load some random icons simply won't show. So far this issue is on chrome, doesn't seem to be in firefox for example.
Any idea what could cause that? Is there anything wrong with my implementation?

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like a duplicate `id` issue to me.  You must make sure that you don't have more than one `id` attribute with the same value in the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had to debug this before, the missing icons would always load after a reload. It lead me to find that, if the page load stalls a bit and the icons are located near the end of the page, the `<use xlink:href="...">` element can't find the symbol it's referencing.

Placing the SVG Icons near the top of the page fixes the issue (before any instance of `<use>`).